# Any hint to solve such a complex limit

Tags: complex-analysis

What would be the limit of the following function: 
$\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow m\pi i} \dfrac{(z-m\pi i) \exp(z)}{\sin z}$ . Can we apply L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: If $m\in\Bbb Z$ you can certainly apply it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it this way:

$$\lim_{z \to m \pi i} \frac{ (z-m \pi i) \exp(z) }{ \sin z } = \lim_{z \to m \pi i} \frac{\exp(z)}{ \frac{\sin z - \sin(m \pi i)}{z - m \pi i} } = \frac{\exp( m \pi i )}{\cos(m \pi i )} = \frac{(-1)^m}{\cosh( m \pi )}.$$

If you prefer, de l'Hospital rule can also be applied.

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, I made a mistake assuming $\sin( m \pi i ) = 0$. The correct solution:

$$\lim_{z \to m \pi i} \frac{ (z-m \pi i) \exp(z) }{ \sin z } = \frac{0 \cdot \exp( m \pi i )}{\sin( m \pi i )} = 0.$$

This also means the l'Hospital rule **cannot** be applied since we don't have a $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: You are mistaken if you assumed $\sin(m\pi i) = 0$.

Comment: Indeed I am! Thank you.

Comment: Except for $m = 0$, where the limit is $1$ (in accordance with the first formula).

Comment: @DanielFischer I hate you guys. ;p Thanks again.